# Sort a table on date value find the value of 3rd record based on 2nd record

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with the below layout. I have populated with sample values.

| sid | status | status_dt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | init | 2023-03-02 |
| 123 | inprog | 2023-03-03 |
| 123 | active | 2023-03-04 |
| 451 | init | 2023-02-22 |
| 451 | inprog | 2023-02-24 |
| 451 | hold | 2023-03-01 |

My question is I need to find all the SID's where the previous status is 'inprog' and current status is anything other than 'active'. I have sorted the table in descending order. But stuck after that, not sure how to go about finding the subsequent value after 'inprog'.

```
select sid, status, status_dt from t1
order by status_dt desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below.

> where the previous status is 'inprog' and current status is anything other than 'active'.

```sql
 SELECT DISTINCT sid 
   FROM sample_table
QUALIFY status <> 'active' AND LAG(status) OVER w = 'inprog'
 WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY sid ORDER BY status_dt);

+-----+
| sid |
+-----+
| 451 |
+-----+
```

**Example #1**

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  select 123 sid, 'init' status,  date '2023-03-02' status_dt union all
  select 123, 'inprog', date '2023-03-03' union all
  select 123, 'active', date '2023-03-04' union all
  select 451, 'init', date '2023-02-22' union all
  select 451, 'inprog', date '2023-02-24' union all
  select 451, 'active', date '2023-03-01'  union all
  select 451, 'hold', date '2023-04-24' union all
  select 451, 'release', date '2023-05-01'
)
 SELECT DISTINCT sid
   FROM sample_table
QUALIFY status <> 'active' AND LAG(status) OVER w = 'inprog'
 WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY sid ORDER BY status_dt);
```

or you can change QUALIFY condition like below.

```
QUALIFY status = 'inprog' AND LEAD(status) OVER w <> 'active'
```

Comment: This almost works. But I missed one detail I should have mentioned in my query. The SID's always appear in sets of 3,  and can appear multiple times. i.e.  
For e.g the SID 451 currently has init, inprog and active, but at a previous date or later date, it can have init, inprog, cancel etc. Basically the 3rd status can keep changing for that set of dates. Not sure if this can be solved easily. I'm still looking into it.

Comment: @RB49, if SID 451 has *init, inprog, active, init inprog, cancel* in a row, what do you expect from this ? still *451* remains in result table ? (current query is to do so).  if you let me know the sample data of edge case and it's expected result, I'll take a look at it again.

Comment: So, let's say for SID 451, the following values are present after sorting by status_dt. INIT, INPROG, ACTIVE, HOLD, RELEASE. Now, if we run your query, this will still return the SID because we are still finding other statuses than 'Active' after 'Inprog', but what I am looking for is, only the value that appears directly after 'Inprog', should not be 'Active'

Comment: @RB49, above query returns nothing for *INIT, INPROG, ACTIVE, HOLD, RELEASE* because it consider the status right next to 'inprog' and check if it's status is *active* or not.  Would you see my updated answer to check if I understand your explanation correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

See if the below helps:

```
with tabstat (sid, status, status_dt) as (
select 123, 'init',  date '2023-03-02' from dual union all
select 123, 'inprog', date '2023-03-03' from dual union all
select 123, 'active', date '2023-03-04' from dual union all
select 451, 'init', date '2023-02-22' from dual union all
select 451, 'inprog', date '2023-02-24' from dual union all
select 451, 'hold', date '2023-03-01' from dual 
)
select t.*, lag(status,1,'') over (partition by sid order by status_dt) prev_status
  , lead(status,1,'') over (partition by sid order by status_dt) nxt_status
from tabstat t
;
```

RTM on window functions.
So, admitting the name of your table is tabstat, your query should be like below:

```
with tb as (
 select t.*, lag(status,1,'') 
   over (partition by sid order by status_dt) prev_status
   ,lead(status,1,'') 
    over (partition by sid order by status_dt) nxt_status
 from tabstat t
```

)
select tb.*
from tb
where tb.status!='active' and tb.prev_status='inprog'

Comment: I've just shared a sample table here. The actual table has thousands of records. Can I just state: select * from t1 within the tabstat table, and use the latter query?

Comment: You certainly can use your actual table name instead of the tabstat I gave for the example. How  else was I to test the code I wrote does not have some syntax error if not by using this CTE?

Comment: I think you misunderstood. Since you've mentioned all 6 sample records and done a 'union all', I was asking since I have thousands of records, instead of doing a 'union all', can I just do a 'SELECT *' would that work?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/51b3c/2) with your data in SQLServer and it shall work in **BigQuery** too.

The following query shall work.

```
select t1.sid, t1.status, t1.status_dt
from your_table t1
where t1.status != 'active' and t1.sid IN (
  select t2.sid
  from your_table AS t2
  where t2.status = 'inprog'
  and t2.status_dt < t1.status_dt
);
```

It gives me the correct result as :

```
sid   status    status_dt
451   hold      2023-03-01
```